# How to connect a AzureContainerApp to an azure hosted PostgreSQL flexible server that isn't open to the internet

Tags: postgresql, azure, networking, azure-container-apps

I've lost a day trying to figure this out so I'm really hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

We have a PostgreSQL (flexibile server) hosted on Microsoft Azure that has no public internet access. (in its own resource group)

We also have a selection of Azure ContainerApp's (using a managed environment) that need to connect to this PostgreSQL server  but for the life of me I can not figure out how to make this happen?

Using AWS, I'd be able to accomplish this with security groups in about 2 seconds but the way containerApps run in a managed environment seems to be causing me some headache.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the below steps to connect a AzureContainerApp to an azure hosted PostgreSQL flexible server that isn't open to the internet.

**Step-1:** Create virtual network with two subnets.
[image]

**Step-2:** While creating Postgres SQL server, select **Private access (VNet Integration)** in **connectivity method** and select the vnet and subnet created in step-1.

[image]

**Step-3:** Next while creating container app, create new container app environment and go to **networking** and choose vnet created in step-1.
[image]

[image]

**Step-4:** Now to check the connectivity from container app to postgres sql server, I connected to a container and used **ping** and **telnet** commands to verfiy.

```
telnet <sql-server-url> 5432
ping <sql-server-url>
```

[image]
[image]